# How to prevent user input data in calendar textbox of Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In my code, I use calendar of Primefaces

```
<p:calendar id="cal" value="#{accountController.selected.mydate}" styleClass="custom" pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm" />
```

- If I use other pattern such as: pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", pattern="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", etc ==> user can not input data in calendar textbox.
- But if I use pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm" ==> user can input data in calendar textbox.

So I want to ask: How can I prevent user input data inside calendar textbox if I use pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm" ?

In Primefaces has any attribute that equivalent with enableManualInput attribute of Richfaces ?.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use readOnlyInputText of calendar. Set the readOnlyInputText to true so that user cannot enter into the input area.